# Does XCOM 2 run on 32-bit systems?

Tags: xcom-2

Can I run XCOM 2 in my 32-bit Windows 7 machine? The recommendation says it needs 64 bit to run the game.

Comment: Have you tried yet? This seems like that should have been done before asking the question, as it'll most likely throw up a follow up question.

Comment: @Texenox Though in this case, OP has read the system requirements and wants to know if he can run the game anyway.

Comment: But what do the *minimum* requirements say?

Comment: http://www.systemrequirementslab.com/cyri/requirements/xcom-2/13025 mentions you need a 64 bit OS at the least, so I'd say you'll have to upgrade.

Comment: No it doesn't unfortunately. Plenty of details [here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/256034/does-xcom-2-run-on-32-bit-systems)

Comment: @XN16, surely you didn't intend to link to the same question you're commenting on.

Comment: @DavidYell That's not really a feasible approach when the game costs $60. I certainly wouldn't be willing to buy it if I wasn't even sure I could run it.

Comment: @ChrisHayes Indeed, but the question doesn't mention that, so from the context it's easy to assume that OP already owns the game.

Comment: Minimum & Recommended System Requirements of XCOM 2
http://www.pcrequirements.net/en/games/xcom-2-system-requirements/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No.

XCOM does not include a 32-bit executable, so it simply will not run on a 32-bit system. It's also likely that a computer old enough to run 32-bit windows 7 fails to meet the other system requirements.

Googling did uncover an unofficial 32-bit mod, but the site it was on did not look trustworthy.

Comment: What?  How old could the site be, the game came out just over a week ago...

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft It had a bunch of fixes and cracks for various old games. Probably a load of viruses.